# Trying to use TMP36 via MCP3008 on Windows 10 iot

Tags: temperature, analog-to-digital, windows-iot

Can't get this working right. Any help very appreciated!

I have a TMP36 on channel 0 of MCP3008 analog to digital converter then into my Raspberry Pi 2.

My code and wiring is in the zip available at this link:

http://t.co/rAzyCWiQw9

My output when reading the MCP3008 converts to int 561 (3 byte array of 0; 2; 49). Unless I'm reading that data wrong, I can't figure out how to convert that to milivolts and thus degrees Celsius.

Comment: Whatever was at the other end of the link is now dead, which renders the question unanswerable. I'm putting it on hold until whatever was in there can be reproduced in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the wiring.  Your reasoning appears to be correct.

To confirm your understanding I suggest you disconnect the temperature sensor from pin 1 of the MCP3008.  Then connect ground to pin 1, expecting a reading of 0, and 5V to pin 1 expecting a reading of 1023 (0, 3, 255).  That would have the merit of confirming the correct operation of everything but the sensor.

---

EDITED TO ADD

From your comments I guess you are a factor of 4 out in the reading as the bits are shifted two bits to the left.

561 will actually be a reading of 561/4 or 140.

140/1024 * 5V (your diagram shows a connection to the 5V pin for AREF) or 684 mV.  Or 18.4 C.  For 30 C you'd need a reading of 800 mV.  If your unregulated supply was 5.85 V (quite possible) that would explain that discrepancy.

---

EDITED TO ADD

The MCP3008 works on bits, unlike the Pi it just sees a bit stream.

It is important to note that the MCP3008 will ignore bits in the bit stream until a high start bit is detected.

As far as the MCP3008 is concerned a transaction is 17 bits long as follows.

```
SB SG D2 D1 D0 
 1  1  0  0  0  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x  x  x  x  x  0 B9 B8 B7 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0
```

This is what the MCP3008 sees if you send 0x06, 0x00, 0x00.   Note the position of the data in the returned bytes.  Also note that as there are excess clocks the MCP3008 starts to return the data again but in least significant bit order.

```
               SB SG D2 | D1 D0 
 0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0 |  0  0  x  x  x  x  x  x | x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x |  x  x  x  0 B9 B8 B7 B6 |B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0 B1 B2
```

This is what the MCP3008 sees if you send 0x01, 0x80, 0x00.  Note the position of the data in the returned bytes.

```
                     SB | SG D2 D1 D0 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 |  1  0  0  0  x  x  x  x |  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
 x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x |  x  x  x  x  x  0 B9 B8 | B7 B6 B5 B4 B3 B2 B1 B0
```

Comment: I tried that idea, ground produces 0 and connecting to 5V produces 4095. That's even more confusing because i thought the MCP3008 had a max output of 10 bits, not 12. I also tried a second different TMP36 and getting the same 561 output.

Comment: There is the proviso of how you transmit the start bit to ensure the returned data is packed conveniently in to bytes.  What byte sequence are you transferring? E.g. for the MCP3202 (a 12 bit device) you send 0x01, 0x80, 0x00 to ensure the returned data is packed in the last 12 bits.

Comment: I think my write buffer is 6,0,0.

Comment: @GaryRitter Looking at the datasheet suggests 0x01, 0x80, 0x00 will align the reading in the last 10 bits of the returned data.

Comment: Joan your write buffer did the trick. Reading 69 degrees F which sounds accurate. Thanks a million! I don't know how to read the datasheet very well, where did you find that?

Comment: @GaryRitter [MCP3008 datasheet](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/MCP3008.pdf) page 21 section 6.1 gives some advice.  Most sections of most datasheets go over my head but even so the MCP3008 is a model of clarity compared to some.

Comment: I see where the 0x01 start bit makes sense, but where did you get 0x80 for the second byte? I'm trying to understand so i don't have to ask questions in the future that i should be able to answer myself.

Comment: @GaryRitter See if the edit I added to the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

http://invent.module143.com/daskal_tutorial/rpi-3-tutorial-11-gpio-analog-sensor-mcp3008-mcp3004/

Check this tutorial out. Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.